# .default.svc.cluster.local on {ip}: no such host

Tags: knative

> I followed this guide. [Knative/GithubSource](https://knative.dev/docs/eventing/samples/github-source/)

During Webhook test, I got an error from log.

```sh
$ kubectl get pod

NAME                                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
githubsourcesample-gltcb-sxz5m-deployment-cd6bd45f7-zpdzl   1/2     Running   0          3s
```

```sh
$ kubectl logs githubsourcesample-gltcb-sxz5m-deployment-cd6bd45f7-zpdzl user-container

2020/01/19 13:02:50 Sink is: "http://github-message-dumper.default.svc.cluster.local", OwnerRepo is: "GRuuuuu/knative-github-source-test"
2020/01/19 13:02:52 Handling push
2020/01/19 13:02:52 unexpected error handling GitHub event: Post http://github-message-dumper.default.svc.cluster.local: dial tcp: lookup github-message-dumper.default.svc.cluster.local on 10.96.0.10:53: no such host
```

**So, My question is :**
1. Why this error happened? Is there any way that I fixed `svc.cluster.local` ip address?
2. I have a domain that connected Internet, Can I change domain `svc.cluster.local` to my domain?

> I also changed external domain by `kubectl edit cm config-domain --namespace knative-serving`. so When I do `kubectl get ksvc`, URL comes correctly as I set.
>   like that:
>
> ```
> $ kubectl get ksvc
> NAME                       URL                                                      LATESTCREATED                    LATESTREADY                      READY   REASON
> github-message-dumper      http://github-message-dumper.default.mydomain.com      github-message-dumper-4zpjk      github-message-dumper-4zpjk      True
> githubsourcesample-gltcb   http://githubsourcesample-gltcb.default.mydomain.com   githubsourcesample-gltcb-sxz5m   githubsourcesample-gltcb-sxz5m   True
> ```

Comment: did you fixed this issue?